# Как отсортировать многомерный массив по определенным ключам на PHP?

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Помогите отсортировать массив по ключам sizes и размерам (42, 46, 44) и sizes_mouth (42, 46, 40) по порядку (42, 44, 46...)

```
Array
(
[2521] => Array
    (
    [cost] => 0
    [price] => 0
    [sizes] => Array
        (
        [42] => Array
            (
            [size] => 42
            )
        [46] => Array
            (
            [size] => 46
            )
        [44] => Array
            (
            [size] => 44
            )
        )
    [sizes_mouth] => Array
        (
        [42] => Array
            (
            [income] => 0
            [order] => 15
            )
        [46] => Array
            (
            [income] => 0
            [order] => 20
            )
        [40] => Array
            (
            [income] => 0
            [order] => 18
            )
        )
    )   
)
```

Должно получиться так

```
Array
(
[2521] => Array
    (
    [cost] => 0
    [price] => 0
    [sizes] => Array
        (
        [42] => Array
            (
            [size] => 42
            )
        [44] => Array
            (
            [size] => 44
            )
        [46] => Array
            (
            [size] => 46
            )
        )
    [sizes_mouth] => Array
        (
        [40] => Array
            (
            [income] => 0
            [order] => 15
            )
        [42] => Array
            (
            [income] => 0
            [order] => 20
            )
        [46] => Array
            (
            [income] => 0
            [order] => 18
            )
        )
    )   
)
```

Comment: Советую почитать про `array_multisort`. Как-раз - эта функция может сортировать многомерные массивы.

Comment: что должно получиться? массив пример

Comment: Поправил, добавил как должно получиться.

Comment: что сверху что снизу одно итоже, а всё увидел

Comment: $i=0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
$keyy[]=$key; # code...
$i++; if($i==1) break;
//$keyy[]=$key;
}

//print_r($keyy);
array_multisort($arr[$keyy[0]]['sizes'], $arr[$keyy[0]]['sizes_mouth']);
print_r($arr);  посмотри так может потянет

Comment: @Dmitry Yakimenko [2521]  Это только в одном элементе сортировать, или их приходит много, типа [2521] [2522][2523] и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это подмножество массивов, то так:

```
array_walk($arr, function($item, $idx) use (&$arr){
    ksort($arr[$idx]['sizes']);
    ksort($arr[$idx]['sizes_mouth']);
});
```

Если это единственный массив, как в вопросе `Array([2521] => Array`, тогда:

```
ksort($arr[2521]['sizes']);
ksort($arr[2521]['sizes_mouth']);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!